# Search and highlight specific text within pdf using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I know theres a lot of posts here regarding searching and finding text in pdf using vba, however that involves Adobe pro which I dont have. Here is the code I have

```
Dim PDF_path As String
Dim searchString As String
Dim waitTime As Date

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

PDF_path = "C:\Users\User\Villaron\SBP Admin Sales - Documents\Clients\Neworks Pty Ltd (Formally PLN) (104)\2022-634 -1596 Sienna Wood, Neerigen Brook\estimating\rev0\structural.pdf"



'Your search string - case-insensitive, as in actual PDF search
searchString = "N12"
'Make sure to provide a complete path to the PDF here
'if your Excel and PDF are in separate folders If AVDoc.Open(PDFPath, "") = True Then

    'Open successful, bring the PDF document to the front.
    AVDoc.BringToFront



'Wait time for a couple of seconds for the PDF file to fully load
waitTime = Now
While DateDiff("5", waitTime, Now) &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt; 2
    DoEvents
Wend

'Send "CTRL + F" keys to the opened PDF to invoke find within that file
'The second argument "true" implies that Excel will wait for the keys to be processed
'before returning control to the macro.
SendKeys "^f", True

'Type the search string in the find box that opens
SendKeys searchString, True

'Hit enter to perform the search
SendKeys "{Enter}", True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Now its not quite working because it has to activate the pdf window to send keys and highlight specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer I support SumatraPDF so anywhere I can search a PDF by adding -search switch, that can be from an Xcell call filename or whatever.

NOTE It can only be found :-) in the latest [3.4 pre-release](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/prerelease), previously you would have [had to script](https://forum.sumatrapdfreader.org/t/command-line-how-to-goto-bookmark-or-find-text-by-named-destination/905/7) much as you do now.

```
>structural.pdf -search N12
```

[image]

Note for standalone single (portable) exe you need to call that first in command line but for my example above, it is using SumatraPDF as the default handler for .PDF commands. For a string with spaces it needs quotes`structural.pdf -search "N12 and N16"` that can work on a line wrap or division (see above) but unlike Acrobat it can not search two nearby words unless there is clear space between them. `structural.pdf -search "N12 N16"`
[image]

Many PDF viewers will have a different but similar method. So for Acrobat enabled browser you could try `file:///C:/path to file/structural.pdf#search='N12'` but MS Edge does not on its own support that convention thus needs a page number or destination.

[image]

If you are using Acrobat reader it has its own command line support for searching but that depends very much on your method of calling, and Adobe are not making it easy for developers by withdrawing previous guidance, you will need to dig deep into their current documentation. but historically was [/A search="One Two" or similar](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-discussions/command-line-syntax-quot-search-quot/m-p/9062416)